# How to loop multidimensional array with condition and count it on another Wordpress page

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have an array of database from a Wordpress page:

> dev-user-20190424.php

```
<?php
$wb_users = array(
    array(

        "Username" => "Azmina",
        "Level" => "form-5",
        "School" => "KOLEJ D PATINGGI ABANG HJ ABDILLAH, SARAWAK",
        "SchoolID" => 4522,

    ),
    array(

        "Username" => "Gudako",
        "Level" => "form-5",
        "School" => "KOLEJ D PATINGGI ABANG HJ ABDILLAH, SARAWAK",
        "SchoolID" => 4522,

    ),
        array(

        "Username" => "Takatosaijo29",
        "Level" => "form-5",
        "School" => "SEKOLAH MENENGAH KEBANGSAAN BAHANG, SABAH",
        "SchoolID" => 4210,

    ),
    array(

        "Username" => "Obon",
        "Level" => "form-5",
        "School" => "SEKOLAH MENENGAH KEBANGSAAN BAHANG, SABAH",
        "SchoolID" => 4210,

    ),
    array(

        "Username" => "Rayana12",
        "Level" => "form-5",
        "School" => "SEKOLAH MENENGAH KEBANGSAAN BAHANG, SABAH",
        "SchoolID" => 4210,

    ),
    array(

        "Username" => "kaiyuanbeh",
        "Level" => "form-5",
        "School" => "SEKOLAH MENENGAH KEBANGSAAN PERMATANG RAWA, PULAU PINANG",
        "SchoolID" => 4250,

    ),
    array(

        "Username" => "Divyabharthi",
        "Level" => "form-5",
        "School" => "SEKOLAH MENENGAH KEBANGSAAN PETALING, WP KL",
        "SchoolID" => 4244,
    ),
    array(

        "Username" => "blackchocolatecake",
        "Level" => "form-4",
        "School" => "SEKOLAH MENENGAH KEBANGSAAN POI LAM, PERAK",
        "SchoolID" => 4375,

    ),
    );
```

So what I am trying to achieve is to display the total number of users on another WordPress page by looping the array $wb-users and if  SchoolID is matched current user school id variable, then count it. Then the total number of users will be displayed on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is basically what you are looking for.

```
$schoolID = 4522;
$studentTotal = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($wb_users); $i++) {
    if ($wb_users[$i]['SchoolID'] === $schoolID) {
        $studentTotal++;
    }
}
```

You need to 
1. Loop through the arrays within the main array. 
2. Compare the 'SchoolID' key with your school ID variable.
3. Increment the counter when there is a match.

Comment: I see. But how do I called the array $wb_users? I would like to display the total number of users on **another WordPress page** let say the page is 'home.php' . Sorry php is not my forte. And I am new to this

Comment: btw I have tried your solution but it does not output any result.

Comment: Using this demo I am able to get output of 2: https://3v4l.org/SItsn

If you only copied and pasted the code from my answer there was no echo or printing to the screen. You would need to handle that in a way for your specific situation.

Comment: For your issue using a variable on different wordpress pages you will probably need to use global variables or add a function to the functions.php file. You may need to get creative for your specific situation. 

Check out this similar stack overflow link: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51145/get-php-variable-from-functions-php-and-echo-it-in-theme-template-files

Answer (score 0):

How about this with `array_count_values` and `array_column`?

```
$counts = array_count_values((array_column($wb_users, 'SchoolID')));
print_r($counts);
```

**Output:**

```
Array( 
        [4522] => 2 
        [4210] => 3 
        [4250] => 1 
        [4244] => 1 
        [4375] => 1 
)
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/hCvq5

Comment: thanks for the response. But my goal is to output the total number of user. say for example I have a Wordpress page 'home.php' and inside that page, there is a column that will output the total number of user. For instance, the current user SchoolID is 4522 so I would like to output the total number of users with the same ID which in this case is two users.

Comment: Did you check my output? it is already saying that user with id `4522` occurs 2 times and user with id `4210` appears 3 times. You need to pass the schoolID to the `$counts` array and get the occurrence.